# Hos to get a json nested in laravel

Tags: arrays, json, laravel, api

I'm use laravel 7

I want a json like this:

```
"declaracion": {
        "situacionPatrimonial": {
            "datosGenerales": {
                "nombre": "Pedro",
                "primerApellido": "Perez",
                "segundoApellido": "García",
                "curp": "BADD110313HCMLNS09",
             }
        }
 }
```

This branch works fine, I have no problem to generate it:

```
"datosGenerales": {
            "nombre": "Pedro",
            "primerApellido": "Perez",
            "segundoApellido": "García",
            "curp": "BADD110313HCMLNS09",
           }
```

My code looks like this

```
$records = [];
    foreach ($declaraciones as $declaracion) {
        $record = [];
        $record['datosGenerales']=$declaracion->datosGeneralesApi($id,$declaracion->servidor_publico);
        $records[] = $record;
        }

        return $records;
```

**datosGeneralesApi it's a trait**

But i don´t know how add above o nest this branches

```
"declaracion": { 
        "situacionPatrimonial": {
```

Please any ideas? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may not quite understand your question, but I hope I can help

```
$records = [];

foreach ($declaraciones as $declaracion) {

  // Here we create the nested items:
  $record = [
    "declaracion" => [
      "situacionPatrimonial" => []
    ]
  ];

  // Now access it
  $record["declaracion"]["situacionPatrimonial"]['datosGenerales'] = $declaracion->datosGeneralesApi($id,$declaracion->servidor_publico);
  $records[] = $record;
}

return $records;
```

You could also consider doing this a couple of other ways, without accessing with keys:

```
  $record = [
    "declaracion" => [
      "situacionPatrimonial" => $declaracion->datosGeneralesApi($id,$declaracion->servidor_publico);
    ]
  ];
  $records[] = $record;
```

Or create it in a much more structured way:

```
// Create the last element:
$situacionPatrimonial = $declaracion->datosGeneralesApi($id,$declaracion->servidor_publico);
// Wrap that in the next element:
$declaration = ["situacionPatrimonial" => $situacionPatrimonial];
// Now create your record, with the wrapped element:
$record = ["declaracion" => $declaration];
$records[] = $record;
```

I hope this explains what you don't understand about nesting even if it doesn't directly answer your question.

Comment: it's just what i need Djave, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [Eloquent API Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-resources). You can easily nest different resources in each other and structure them in any way you want.